# Ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Вот такую ошибку выдаёт:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in
>   /home/b/b67855gz/b67855gz.beget.tech/public_html/admin/controller/extension/module/arproductday.php
>   on line 29

Ниже код с 13 по 29 строку.

```
            if(isset($this->request->post['product'])){
            $offset_time = time();

            $items = $this->request->post['product'];

            while ($items) {
                $insert = array();

                foreach (array_slice($items, 0, 250) as $item) {
                    $insert[] = "'" . (int)$item['id'] . "','" . (int)$item['quantity']  . "','" . (int)$item['week'] . "'";
                }

                if ($insert) {
                    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "ar_productday (product_id, quantity, week) VALUES (" . implode("),(", $insert) . ") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = VALUES(quantity), week = VALUES(week)");
                }
            }﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿
        }
```

В чём может быть проблема? Вроде синтаксис соблюдал, ошибок не нашел

Comment: не по теме, но зачем целочисленные параметры в кавычки в запросе вставлять? а так смотрите файл целиком, где-то что-то явно пропущено.

Comment: а что вы планируете делать то таким циклом вообще? вставлять несколькими запросами по 250 штук? дак `array_slice` не меняет исходный массив, если `$items` не пуст, то там в принципе вечный цикл?

Comment: Поместите в любой редактор с проверкой синтаксиса (даже в интернете) и он вам подскажет что не так.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov мне пришлось откатить вашу правку, потому что ваша правка исправляла ошибку (уж не знаю, каким чудом, но исправляла)

Comment: Если посмотреть этот код в hex-редакторе, то перед } обнаруживается мусор из [маркеров последовательности байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) (невидимый символ FEFF). Если его стереть, то ошибка пропадает

Answer (score 1):

Попробовал добавить скобку `}` на 29 строке?

А так, открой файл в PHPStorm или подобное IDE, и там визуально закрывай частями код.
Например так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока не дойдёте до нужной строки.

Или можете добавить тут файлик, чтобы все могли посмотреть код.